# How to change css when scroll(0,0) bottom to top

Tags: css, scroll

I just want change css property when scroll top of the page... not the bottom...
I tried

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    $(".class").css("position", "absolute");
  //here change default position(fixed) when scroll(0.0)
});
```

Comment: [jQuery.scrollTop](https://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/) is what you need

Comment: #Eric Martinez thanks for your interest to answer... I solved the problem... Not using the srollTop()...